# How to move a Git directory without causing havoc

Tags: linux, git, filesystems, mount

I have the following file structure, and `/var/www/website1` is being tracked by Git.

```
/var/www/website1/directory1/subdirectory1_1/
/var/www/website1/directory1/subdirectory1_2/
/var/www/website1/directory2/subdirectory2_1/
/var/www/website1/html/
```

I now wish to move `/var/www/website1/directory1/subdirectory1_2/` to `/home/user1/subdirectory1_2/`, but then mount this directory back at its original location.  But if I move the directory, Git is going to think they have all been deleted out of the Git directory, right?  Can I temporarily turn Git off while I make the changes?  Will doing this cause any hardship?

PS.  If you are curious why I am doing this, please see https://superuser.com/questions/752226/giving-remote-access-to-files-for-only-a-single-directory-on-a-linux-server

Comment: It was meant to be a comment. Reposting so others can see: hat do you mean by "mount this directory back at its original location"? Like crating a sym link ln -s /home/user1/subdirectory1_2 /var/www/website1/directory1/subsirectory1_2? I am still trying to figure out what the mount part is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
But if I move the directory, Git is going to think they have all been deleted out of the Git directory, right?
```

No, Git is smart enough to figure it out.  I moved the directory and mounted it back as described, and Git resolved the changes and showed no modified or deleted files as desired.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to turn off Git. Just simply clone the repository to the new location /home/user1/subdirectory1_2/ and delete the old repository (you can take a backup for safety). Git is a distributed version control system and if you **simply clone** a repository, it would be a complete copy including all your history and you can work independently as usual on the new repo.

Comment: I wish the location to remain at `/var/www/website1/`.  Sure, I can delete the repository, and reclone it, but it would remain the same.  I just one a subdirectory to be mounted on a different filesystem.  If I clone it, how would Git/Linux know to put a given subdirectory on a different filesystem?

Comment: I could not get the exact requirement. But from my understanding I think this could be solved by adding as a git submodule for this folder.